# Choosing a Maya to JSON library

Tags: javascript, json, maya

I've been searching for a JS library that can encode scenes from Maya to JSON and found [Inka3D](http://www.inka3d.com/), [CopperLicht](http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/index.html), plus [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/).  I need a library because I'm not that good with JS in fact all I've done has pretty much been with PHP and some jQuery.  I wan't the ability to export scenes, map keyframes with user interaction etc.. Which would be best for someone with a background in PHP?

Comment: Maya to JSON, is that even possible in the first place? Realistically, it doesn't make much sense, converting a complex file format into a serialized plain text format.

Comment: I thought so, then I found Inka3d which is basically a Maya plugin that exports scenes for WebGL enabled apps, then I thought since the canvas and scene are only 300X200px, I could just encode to JSON without a library.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible.

Comment: So what your saying is I'm going to have to use WebGL?  Is there another way to load a small 3D model in an html5 canvas? Thanks for replying.

Comment: No, I'm saying that there is no easy way to convert Maya to JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the creator of Inka3D I recommend using it since it is intended to solve your problem. You can control exported scenes from js using the maya parameter names. Key frames and mel expressions are exported, also shading networks

Comment: This looks great for larger projects, for what I required I just drew a model in Maya, exported it as .obj, then rendered it in WebGL using Three.js.  Thank god for you devs, these scripts absolutely rock!